# Proper way for 2 nodejs apps to communicate together

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

We have 2 apps; one master and one slave.

Master polls a database every 30 seconds and fetch jobs.

Slave processes the job received from the master.

So far we've been experimenting with ws and socket.io.

Ultimately we'd like to use node-cluster on the Master as well.

Can anyone shine some light to which module we need to accomplish such task?

Thank you in advance.